# Mocha assertion object.should.equal(a or b)

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, assertion

Using mocha how do I assert whether an object is equal to more than one value?

`obj.should.equal('true\n' || 'false\n', "value is invalid");`

Does not seem to work.  It is only comparing obj to `true\n`.  I have tried various different syntax for this with no luck.  All of the answers I have found online require me to use Chai, but I would much rather solve this using Mocha.

Please note that true and false are just examples.  I would preferably learn to be able to compare to anything, for example obj equals pizza or apples

First post so any tips on posting better would also be welcome, thanks!

Comment: Mocha is just the test runner. You're probably already using Chai/Should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I'm reading [the documentation](http://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/) correctly, it looks as if [`.to.satisfy`](http://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#satisfymatcher-msg) is what is needed.

Since `.to.satisfy` takes a function that returns a boolean, you should be able to run your tests like so:

```
expect(obj).to.satisfy(function (value) {
    var matches = [
        true,
        false,
    ];
    return matches.indexOf(value) > -1;
}, "value is invalid");

expect(obj).to.satisfy(function (value) {
    var matches = [
        'true\n',
        'false\n',
    ];
    return matches.indexOf(value) > -1;
}, "value is invalid");

expect(obj).to.satisfy(function (value) {
    var matches = [
        'pizza',
        'apples',
    ];
    return matches.indexOf(value) > -1;
}, "value is invalid");
```

This general pattern should work, provided you need strict equality (as that's what [`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Description) uses internally.)